# Why does trim() not work for setting a string within an object (related to type, not the nature of the state)

Tags: reactjs

I could not figure this out. Eventually created a code sandbox to try and isolate the issue and found that even stripped down, the issue persists.

I have a controlled input that should not allow the space character. `e.target.value.trim()` correctly trims the space characters when the state is stored as a string but allows them when the state is part of an object.

So this works correctly:

```
const [primitivestring, setPrimitiveString] = useState("");
...

<input
        value={primitivestring}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const trimmedValue = e.target.value.trim();
          setPrimitiveString(trimmedValue);
        }}
      />
```

But this does not:

```
const [newuserState, setnewuserState] = useState({ email: "" });
...
 
<input
        placeholder="Email address/Username"
        id="email"
        type="email"
        value={newuserState.email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const trimmedValue = e.target.value.trim();
          console.log({
            trimmedValue,
            trimmedValueLength: trimmedValue.length
          });
          setnewuserState({ ...newuserState, email: trimmedValue });
        }}
      />
```

Link to code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-hugle-7cw6tv?file=/src/App.js:353-772

Why is this happening?

Another quirk (and secondary question) - the character counter for the 'buggy' input does not update when a space character is typed BUT it does update the count (including the space characters) when a non-space character is eventually typed. Why?

Update - As per the accepted answer, the issue was to do with `type="email"` and entirely unrelated to how the value in question is being stored in state. Still unclear why this issue is as it is. This thread touches on it: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6368 - if anybody has more info or a clear explanation, I would love to know more.

Comment: second one create a new object which is a change.

Comment: you can add a condition if(newuserState.email!=trimmedValue){do the stuff here}

Comment: Isn't trim() designed to remove duplicate spaces and leave only one? if you want to remove ALL spaces then substitute()?

Comment: @AnoopJoshiP Yes I can add that 'if' statement but why is the need to do so there?

Comment: @SolarMike No trim removes any leading/trailing spaces. So, expected behaviour would be for a space character to be ignored and for e.target.value to only ever have a single space character since it should be replaced. I.e. Typing space should be trimmed, in turn, the value of the controlled input does not change, in turn, subsequent space characters, if typed, will (should) be the only space character there.

Comment: @Hemal Have you read the help entry for trim(). "Removes all spaces from a text string except for single spaces between words." So leading, trailing as you say, BUT also multiple spaces in the string...

Comment: Spaces between words in the string, in this context, should not matter. The controlled nature of the component should mean no spaces are ever entered/reflected in state unless the user types something, then moves the cursor to the middle of the string, and then inserts spaces there (in which case trim will not remove them). As the accepted answer (and experimenting with trim quite a lot) shows, it isn't the use of trim here that is the issue but a discrepancy between react and the dom when type="email". I found this: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6368 that helps too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type="email"` is throwing things off. Emails cannot have spaces, so it looks like React, when it sees an input field of type email where the value has a space, does not fire its `onChange` handler because the input is invalid.

Remove the `type="email"` and it'll work as expected.

> the character counter for the 'buggy' input does not update when a space character is typed BUT it does update the count (including the space characters) when a non-space character is eventually typed. Why?

Same reason - if the value has a space, it's not a valid email, so the handler doesn't fire.

```js
function App() {
  const [primitivestring, setPrimitiveString] = React.useState("");
  const [newuserState, setnewuserState] = React.useState({ email: "" });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sample input component</h1>
      <h2>Spaces should be trimmed but are not</h2>
      <input
        placeholder="Email address/Username"
        id="email"
        value={newuserState.email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          const trimmedValue = e.target.value.trim();
          setnewuserState({ email: trimmedValue });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: You're right! Removing email type does indeed fix things. Follow up question - if the handler does not fire, then why does the space character show up in the input? I.e - It is a controlled input and it's value is being set by the onChange handler. If React is not firing that, then typing 'abc def' should not be possible right?

Comment: It seems very weird. It feels like a bug, though I've gone through a bunch of search results and haven't seen any documentation about this or anyone else running into this issue. Yeah, with a controlled component, even an invalid input would *seem* like it should make the component re-render (and let the script-writer handle it), rather than apparently going uncontrolled.

Comment: Is that what is happening? The component is becoming temporarily uncontrolled, wherein the value includes spaces, and then becoming controlled again? If so, that is very weird. I found this too: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6368 . I think, I will just leave off the type="email" as it seems detrimental in this scenario vs simply handling the validation myself. Thanks!

Comment: happens the same for me